# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, bcrypt

code:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def auth
        if params[:name].present? && params[:pass].present? && params[:role].present?
                @name=params[:name]
                pass=params[:pass]
                role=params[:role]

                epass = BCrypt::Password.new(pass)
        else
                render "argerror"
        end
  end
end
```

Error:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):
app/controllers/login_controller.rb:12:in `new'
app/controllers/login_controller.rb:12:in `auth'
```

Password Encryption Mechanism:

```
salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
pass = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(pass, salt)
```

The above code product "BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash" error. My requirement is to get the username and password from client and validate
it with the data stored in db. In database I stored the hashed password for users which is encrypted by bcrypt. So, now I tried to
encrypt the password which is entered by client. After encrypt the current password, it is matched with hashed password stored in db. But it produce the error. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `BCrypt::Password.new` the hash you have stored in the database, not the password the user is submitting. Then you compare that with input received from the user.

Example:

```
# Create hash of password
pass =  BCrypt::Password.create('TestPassword')
=> "$2a$10$3.D6D2htbiRrezmZUhePV.gaQlc3ZjFYD9hv43khN5eWP5y8BGUXG"

# Pass the hash you have stored to Password.new
db_hash = BCrypt::Password.new("$2a$10$3.D6D2htbiRrezmZUhePV.gaQlc3ZjFYD9hv43khN5eWP5y8BGUXG")

# Compare the input from the user to the password stored
db_hash == "TestPassword"
=> true

db_hash == "NotRealPassword"
=> false
```

You can find some more info here: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby#how-to-use-bcrypt-ruby-in-general

Also, if you're using Rails >= 3 I'd look into using `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` with your User model. Some more info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Can you explain how it is validate password. Because, db have hashed password and we have plain password. We just pass the hashed password to "BCrypt::Password.new(user.password)". What I expect is we need to get the hash for the submitted password and using that hash, we can check with the password stored in db to validate the user login credential. But here somemore different.

Comment: Sure. 

`BCrypt::Password.new(user.password)` has a public method of `==` so when you call `db_hash == "plain_text"` what it does under the hood is encrypt the plain text you pass it, then compare if the hashes are the same.

You can see the source for `==` in `BCrypt` here: http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html#M000009
I hope that explains - please let me know if not.

Comment: So, here the "==" is not the same operator which we use in string comparison. Is it right ?

Comment: Nearly. Sorry if my explanation was poor. What `BCrypt` does is override and add some functionality to the `==` operator. When you call `==` on `BCrypt::Password.new` it calls the ruby default `==` on the result of `BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(secret, @salt)`.